# How to edit script for Google Sheets script that e-mails user when a numerical cell is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet that multiple people will edit. There is a cell (I1), that has a numerical count that is automatically updated based on data entry conditions (I.e. it will change from 14, to 15 if someone adds an other entry in a different area of the sheet). I would like to get an e-mail when the cell value changes. I did some research and found an example like this:

```
function sendEmailAlert() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheetname = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var cell = ss.getCurrentCell()
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var row = cell.getRow();

  var Toemail = 'email@gmail.com';
  var subject = 'New Entry -' + ss.getName();
  var body = 'Your file has a new entry in - ' + sheetname + ' Updated by - ' + user +
' check file now- ' + ss.getUrl();


  if(col === 2 |col === 1) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject, body);
 }

};
```

This will notify me if an active sheet has a change in column A or B it seems. Close, but I'm not good enough at coding to do specifically what I want. What can I try next?

I tried my best to use other examples, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, about `There is a cell (I1), that has a numerical count that is automatically updated based on data entry conditions (I.e. it will change from 14, to 15 if someone adds an other entry in a different area of the sheet).`, can you provide the detail of `a numerical count that is automatically updated based on data entry conditions`? And, I'm worried that in your situation, it might be required to check `a different area of the sheet`. Because Google Apps Script cannot detect the cell value which is changed by a formula.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you help me alter the code to where it only watches for when column I is altered instead? I think my current code checks for Column A or B,  but this time I just want I. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `but this time I just want I`, I think that only column "I" can be checked. But, I cannot understand the relationship between your question and your reply. I would like to propose a modified script by correctly understanding your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: If @Tanaike cannot understand this question, then the question is definitively missing an [mcve]. Let's close this until it can be clarified.

Comment: @Tanaike, I have figured it out for my purposes, do you know how I can edit the code above to only work on a specifically named spreadsheet, and a specific tab name on the spreadsheet? I hope that makes sense. Currently the code just works for any active sheet. Thanks.